# Proof Help in Real Analysis with sets dealing with Irrational Numbers

Tags: real-analysis

The Question: Let $\mathbb{I} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, which $\mathbb{I}$ is the set of irrational numbers. Prove if $a < b$, then there exits $x \in \mathbb{I}$ such that $a<x<b$. (**HINT:**  First show that $ A= (r+\sqrt2: r \in \mathbb{Q}) \subseteq \mathbb{I}$ ).

The attempt: Let $\mathbb{I}$ and $A$ be as stated. Using the hint, suppose by contradiction, $A \not\subset \mathbb{I}$, which means that $x \in A$ and $x \not\in \mathbb{I}$. This means that x is a rational number. Since $x \in A$, we can express $x$ as $x= r + \sqrt{2}$ which $r \in \mathbb{Q}$. However, this implies that $x-r= \sqrt{2}$, $x-r$ is a rational number,  and $\sqrt{2} \not\in \mathbb{Q}$. This is a contradiction. Therefore this implies the negation of the statement is false, which means that $x \in \mathbb{I}$. Hence $A \subseteq \mathbb{I}$.

I do not know what else to do for the second part, if there is one. Can you guys give me some hints onto how to finish this proof.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You know that $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R,$ that is, if $a<b$ then there exists some rational number $r$ such that $a<r<b.$ 
Now, let $a$ and $b$ be as in your statement. Then $a-\sqrt2<b-\sqrt2$ and therefore there exists $r\in\mathbb Q$ such that $a-\sqrt2<r<b-\sqrt2\iff a<r+\sqrt2<b.$